# The search functionality in wordpress admin panel not working

Tags: php, wordpress, search

When I open my WordPress admin panel and search for a specific page, the results will always show the same pages. it seems that the search functionality is not working. I have tried to search for posts as well in the post section but it not working as well.

[screen shot of the search bar in the admin panel in wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8wdb.png)

If anyone can guide me on how to fix this issue please.

Comment: When you submit the form, are you showing any query parameters in the address bar?

Comment: This is the original link: https://www.ihna.edu.au/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page 

When I search for "courses" for example, this is what I get: https://www.ihna.edu.au/wp-admin/edit.php?s=courses&post_status=all&post_type=page&action=-1&m=0&seo_filter&readability_filter&paged=1&action2=-1

Comment: @plushyObject Was that an answer to your question?

Comment: It was but it creates more questions than it has answered.

Does the search work on the front-end of the site? If you just use `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` in one of your templates?

Comment: So I tested the search functionality in the front end, it gives me the results of my desired search at the top of the search, but it still shows up everything else in the results. It doesn't narrow down the search

Comment: @Suhayb Have you installed any new plugin recently?

Comment: Do you remember when search was working last time? Uninstall any latest plugin that you have installed and try then.

Answer (score 1):

```
You may find this helpful.

add_filter('pre_get_posts','grup_search_filter_products');
    function grup_search_filter_products($query) {
        // Frontend search only
        if ( $query->is_search() && !is_admin() ) {...
    
    !is_admin() //must be a`enter code here
```

Comment: If you find your post or page default search functionality is not working then find this 'pre_get_posts' hook and then filter function condition add this statement '!is_admin()' then the admin dashboard not change their default functionality.